# Oracle unexpected sorting behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, row-number

Consider the Following:

```
CREATE TABLE TestPersons
(
PersonID int,
Name varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255)
)

insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (1, 'name1', 'firstname1', 'adress1');
insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (2, 'name2', 'firstname2', 'adress2');
insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (3, 'name3', 'firstname3', 'adress3');
insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (4, 'name4', 'firstname4', 'adress4');
```

**First Query (works fine):**

```
SELECT name, firstname, personid, count(name), row_number() over (ORDER BY name, firstname) as rn
FROM testpersons
GROUP BY name, firstname, personid
```

returns:

```
name1   firstname1  1   1   1
name2   firstname2  2   1   2
name3   firstname3  3   1   3
name4   firstname4  4   1   4
```

**Second Query (unexpected result):**

```
SELECT name, firstname, personid, count(name), row_number() over (ORDER BY name desc, firstname desc) as rn
FROM testpersons
GROUP BY name, firstname, personid
```

returns for all rows name4 and firstname4:

```
name4   firstname4  4   1   1
name4   firstname4  3   1   2
name4   firstname4  2   1   3
name4   firstname4  1   1   4
```

I would expect a changed order of the result from the first query.

Any Idea why is that?

---

Output of `select * from v$version` is as follows:

```
Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production   0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production  0
"CORE   12.1.0.1.0  Production" 0
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production 0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production  0
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding how your second query would ever produce those results... Perhaps you can create a fiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Fiddle doesnt work for oracle somewhy, thats why i attached the code, all you need is to run it

Comment: Not sure what's going on with `oracle` on fiddle, but this works using another database that supports `window functions`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7fb5d/1

Comment: MSSQL works fine too, its just with oracle... can not explain this !

Comment: Please try is by removing desc from  'over (ORDER BY name desc' it may causes the issue OR you can try it by adding ORDER BY clause

Comment: @SBohara All columns not listed in the order by with desc work fine, but i need the sorting, as u can see the first query works fine, as soon as desc is used  instead of asc which is the default behaviour i get wrong results

Comment: Please add the output of `select * from v$version` to your question. This sounds like you are hit by the issue described in `Doc ID 2135921.1` (which references the unpublished Bug 22916353) Check the description on [MyOracleSupport](https://support.oracle.com)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ic cant open the link you sent, and googling the Doc Id wasnt really helpful, what is it about, do u have another link?

Comment: You need an account with Oracle. Oracle does not allowe to make that information public.

Comment: I have an account but it doesnt seem to include support issues, somehowthey need a Support Identifier

Comment: So is it a BUG from my Oracle Version? are there any patches for this? or is it my query that is wrong

Comment: @CloudyMarble - what a_horse_... meant is a "paid" (commercial) account with Oracle. I am an enthusiast learning Oracle on my own, I downloaded 11.2 XE on my laptop and 12.1 EE on my desktop for free, Oracle makes free copies available for learning and evaluation (but not for commercial use). One of the limitations is that I do not have access to Support, and in particular to the bug database, I can't report bugs (of which I found several, discussed a few on OTN), etc. You may be in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are talking about. Below is a direct copy and paste from my session where I entered the commands as you posted them. I get the correct result from the second query.

Is there something you didn't tell us? What version of Oracle are you using? How are you interacting with it? What is your front-end? Do you send your queries directly or through some app?

What you see below is Oracle 11.2 XE, SQL*Plus front-end.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TestPersons
  2  (
  3  PersonID int,
  4  Name varchar(255),
  5  FirstName varchar(255),
  6  Address varchar(255)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (1, 'name1', 'firstname1', 'adress1');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (2, 'name2', 'firstname2', 'adress2');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (3, 'name3', 'firstname3', 'adress3');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into TestPersons(PersonID, Name, FirstName , Address) Values (4, 'name4', 'firstname4', 'adress4');
1 row created.

SQL> column name format a10
SQL> column firstname format a18

SQL> SELECT name, firstname, personid, count(name), row_number() over (ORDER BY name, firstname) as rn
  2  FROM testpersons
  3  GROUP BY name, firstname, personid;

NAME       FIRSTNAME            PERSONID COUNT(NAME)         RN
---------- ------------------ ---------- ----------- ----------
name1      firstname1                  1           1          1
name2      firstname2                  2           1          2
name3      firstname3                  3           1          3
name4      firstname4                  4           1          4

4 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT name, firstname, personid, count(name), row_number() over (ORDER BY name desc, firstname desc) as rn
  2  FROM testpersons
  3  GROUP BY name, firstname, personid;

NAME       FIRSTNAME            PERSONID COUNT(NAME)         RN
---------- ------------------ ---------- ----------- ----------
name4      firstname4                  4           1          1
name3      firstname3                  3           1          2
name2      firstname2                  2           1          3
name1      firstname1                  1           1          4

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Im using ORA12C (Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production) and had the same results with Frontends SQL-Developer Version 3.0.04 and verison 4

Comment: OK, I just tested on Oracle 12.1 EE (Enterprise Edition), and in both cases - earlier and now - I used SQL Developer (and for what I posted, SQL\*Plus as well). In all cases I get the same, correct result from the second query. If there is a problem, it must be with your setup, it is not an Oracle bug (since the exact same commands produce the correct results on my system).

Comment: Tried it with SQL-Plus produces the same wrong results. it would wonder me if the Enterprise edition has a different way of executing queries.

Comment: As I said, what I posted in my Answer was run on 11.2 XE (Express Edition, different from the Enterprise Edition) with the same result.